# Nested fixed element not work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm trying to put a `fixed` element within another `fixed` element like this

```
<div class="wrapper-fixed">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="element-fixed">
            <p>I'm fixed in Chrome, FF</p>
            <p>Why not in IE ?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll the page in Chrome and FF `element-fixed` stay `fixed` but in IE it scrolls too and I guess that should not happen because a `fixed` element is outside the document flow.

I tried pulling it out of the `content` but did not work, pulling it out of `wrapper-fixed` it does but in my case I can't.

[HERE A JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/prvrw2yh/1/) similar to my real situation

So why that happens and how fix it without pulling it out of `wrapper-fixed`

Adding images to illustrate the problem:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with IE11. Which version gives you this behavior?

Comment: I tried in IE9 and it works as expected there too. Edit: even in IE8.

Comment: [`fixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531140.aspx) is supported since IE7 (requires DTD though). Are you running the page in Quirks mode?

Comment: @Teemu My browser is IE 11.0.9600.16384

Comment: @Mr Lister I added some pictures to show the problem

Comment: Oh! When the fiddle is so narrow that the rounded rectangle falls partially outside the viewport, it does stay fixed. Only when you make the fiddle wide enough, it does scroll with the paragraphs. That's why I didn't see the bug at first! And this happens in IE11 but not in IE9. (Don't have IE10 here to test.) You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Change your wrapper position to absolute

```
.wrapper-fixed{
    position: absolute;
    ...
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/za4hdmpf/

**Option 2**

Won't be suitable as this requires a solution that does not involve pulling element-fixed out of wrapper-fixed.

<strike>Change your markup and make position adjustments to your element-fixed</strike>

```
<div class="wrapper-fixed">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>        
        <p>Content 1</p>        
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>        
        <p>Content 4</p>
        <p>Content 5</p>        
        <p>Content 6</p>
        <p>Content 7</p>   
        <p>.</p>  
        <p>.</p>  
        <p>.</p>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="element-fixed">
    <p>I'm fixed in Chrome, FF</p>
    <p>Why not in IE ?</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.element-fixed{
    position: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -290px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vuykwu76/

Comment: Why `absolute`, if OP wants `fixed`?

Comment: the wrapper-fixed's parent is the body. That makes it behave pretty similar to fixed.

Comment: Actually, I can see the issue with OP's fiddle (my browser is IE 11.0.9600.17842).

Comment: Yes, it works but believe me in my case I can not change the position: fixed in the wrapper, thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest but I specified in the question: "how fix it without pulling it out of wrapper-fixed"

Comment: No problem, every solution is welcome, maybe don't works for me but perhaps it help another user

Comment: Since it's clearly a bug, I wouldn't jump trough hoops to get a working workaround. Maybe it'll be fixed with the next upgrade to IE11.